# Getting error while assiging the address of an element in C++

Tags: c++

I have two classes, `Class A` and `class B`. My code is written below. I am getting an error which i have mentioned at the end.

```
class A
{    
    Private:
        B Labels
        ....
        ....    
};

A::method()
{
    Labels.add (label_mark);
    ....
    ....
}

A::save()
{
....
....
    for (int i = 0; i < Labels.size (); i++)
    {
        const B& Labels = Labels[i]; //GETTING ERROR HERE

        fprintf (file,"%d\n",
                i + 1,
                Labels.timestamp.toString ("%H:%M:%S").c_str (),

    }
}
```

I am getting an **error**

`error: no match for ‘operator[]’ in ‘Labels[i]’`

Comment: hazmatLabels is defined as normal variable(not pointer type) hence you are getting this compile error.

Comment: What is LandmarkLists defined as?

Comment: i am using the similar code for another file...and it is working fine

Comment: Can you show how hazmatLabels is getting created by your class HazmatDetecor??

Comment: i have updated my considerable amount of relevant code...please have a look

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are hiding the name of your `B` here:

```
const B& Labels = Labels[i];
```

When you do this, `Labels` on the RHS is a `const B&`, and this has no `operator[]`.

You need to pick a different name:

```
const B& foobar = Labels[i];
```